# Perform Logoff incase any of the transaction got failed

Tags: jmeter

i have 10 transactions,first one is login and has multiple transactions & last one is logout, if any of the user action got failed then directly need to perform log off

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) and check `${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}` [pre-defined variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars) status and if it's not `true` - call the [Module Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller) which will execute the [Test Fragment](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) responsible for the logout.

Check out [Easily Write a GOTO Statement in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/easily-write-a-goto-statement-in-jmeter) for example implementation if needed.